# share files between Debian Wheezy and Windows 8 on LAN

Tags: windows-8, network-shares, lan, debian-wheezy

How to Share files between Debian Wheezy and Windows 8? let's suppose my Debian User name is Wheezy and Password is Linux, and my Windows 8 user name is Windows and session login password is Microsoft, what information should I use to share files on LAN network?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

On the Debian box, in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install samba
sudo smbpasswd -a wheezy
```

By default, Samba will try to keep your Linux and Samba passwords synchronized, so when prompted, enter the same password here you use with your normal login on the Debian box. Next in the terminal, do

```
/sbin/ifconfig | grep "inet addr"
```

This will give you the IP address of the Debian box.  Let's pretend it's 192.168.0.10 for the sake of this next step.

On the windows machine, hold the Windows key and press R.  When you release both, a Run Dialog should pop up.  In the box, type

```
 \\192.168.0.10\home\wheezy
```

Windows should prompt you for a username/password to connect with. Use "wheezy" as the username and use the password you entered above.

This should get you started with sharing files in your home directory on the Debian machine. For more information on Samba's configuration options, see http://samba.org/