# Accessing a shared user account among many Linux machines throughout the home

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I have multiple computers running Linux, and I use them for different tasks. However, I'd like to create a user login system similar to Windows, in which  I type my username, password, and domain, and can log in to get my user's desktop, documents, and programs no matter which Linux computer in the house I log in from.

How would I be able to do this, and what would I need?

Any help would be appreciated.

Sincerely, 
nvanw27

Comment: Mint should have it's own GUI login screen already, does it not work? Or maybe  you don't have multiple users, does it auto-login one user? Or are you talking about a remote login, like through ssh or a remote desktop?

Comment: I've got two users on the main computer, plus a guest account. The other computer is a laptop, and i'm in the process in adding another laptop. I'm mainly trying to make a domain where I can access the same information from every computer without initiating a remote desktop connection.

Comment: So just sharing files to any computer on your local network would be good enough?

Comment: Yes. I knew how to set something like this up on Windows, but I don't have the resources or time available to do it there.

Comment: Here's a similar Q&A that might work, I think Mint already has samba installed. https://superuser.com/questions/738054/share-files-between-debian-wheezy-and-windows-8-on-lan

Comment: Put your home directory on a network share (such as a NAS system). As Linux traditionally stores all of a user's settings and files in a user's home directory, this will ensure that you have a consistent desktop experience on every machine.